# Linear transformation from complex to polynomial of degree 2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is there a linear transformation $T:C^4 -> P_2(C)$ such that $im(T)= P_2(C)$?

Comment: Yep! You can make one by mapping a basis of $\Bbb{C}^4$ onto a basis for $P_2(\Bbb{C})$, and extending linearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like
$$T(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)=w_1t^2+w_2t+w_3$$
can work.